# Let $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\text{Poisson}(\mu)$ be independent real-valued random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent integer-valued random variables, then 
$$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}P(X=m)P(Y=n-m)$$ to prove that

> $X+Y\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda+\mu)$

We've got $P(X=n)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$ and $P(Y=n)=e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^n}{n!}$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$ Then 
from above, 
$$P(X+Y=n)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}P(X=m)P(X=n-m)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}.$$ 
But where do I go from here? I feel like it's probably just some calculus that I've forgotten, but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

We have for $k \ge 0$:
\begin{align*}
  P(X+ Y =k) &= \sum_{i = 0}^k P(X+ Y = k, X = i)\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^k P(Y = k-i , X =i)\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^k P(Y = k-i)P(X=i)\\X
    &= \sum_{i=0}^k e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^{k-i}}{(k-i)!}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}\\
   &= e^{-(\mu + \lambda)}\frac 1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}\mu^{k-i}\lambda^i\\
   &= e^{-(\mu + \lambda)}\frac 1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki\mu^{k-i}\lambda^i\\
   &= \frac{(\mu + \lambda)^k}{k!} \cdot e^{-(\mu + \lambda)}
\end{align*}
Hence,  $X+ Y \sim \mathcal P(\mu + \lambda)$.

Comment: Thank you, but why is it a finite sum?

Comment: Because $X+Y$ can only equal $k$ if both $X \leq k$, $Y \leq k$ as $X \geq 0$, $Y \geq 0$

Comment: Ahhh, thank you.

Comment: Actually, why do we have that theyre both nonnegative? The assumption is just that they are real-valued.

Comment: Try evaluating the PMF for negative $k$.

Comment: @Gengar The assumption is that the random variables follow a *Poisson distribution*; for which the support is the *non-negative integers*.  For all other real-values, the probabilitymeasure is zero.